# react list not rendering updated state data

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I'm trying to render some updated data from an api call as a list of items but my map function doesn't output anything? I'm not getting any errors my code just doesn't return anything from my map inside of inputNode()

am I perhaps calling the function from some improper scope? I tested the condition and it works as expected without map()

hoping someone can school me here ;)

```
inputNode = () => {  
          
          if(this.state.weatherData === null) {
            return(
              <div>
                nothing here
              </div>
            )
          }else{
          
           this.state.weatherData.map((period, index)=>{
              return(
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>{period.name}</p>
                  <h3>forecast</h3>
                  <p>{period.shortForecast}</p>
                  <p>{period.temperature}</p>
                  <p>from {period.startTime} to {period.endTime}</p>
                </div>
                )
              })
            }         
          }


 render() {  
            return <div className={styles.container}>{this.inputNode()}</div> 
           }
```

Comment: `return this.state.weatherD...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you forgot to return the result of a map function in your else block:

```
inputNode = () => {  
          
          if(this.state.weatherData === null) {
            return(
              <div>
                nothing here
              </div>
            )
          }else{
          
           return this.state.weatherData.map((period, index)=>{ // add return here
              return(
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>{period.name}</p>
                  <h3>forecast</h3>
                  <p>{period.shortForecast}</p>
                  <p>{period.temperature}</p>
                  <p>from {period.startTime} to {period.endTime}</p>
                </div>
                )
              })
            }         
          }
```